# how to get values selected in multiple selection box from ejs template to server side node?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, postgresql, ejs

I am working on one node, express project in which I need values from multiple selected selection box from EJS file to node file then how can I do that?

1.EJS file

```
<select id="val" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
```

2.Server side JavaScript file

```
export const getValues = aysnc (req, res) => {
   try{
    const { val } = req.body;
    console.log(val);
}
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get these values on a form submit action? If so, please show your form and route. If not, describe the JS AJAX behavior you want to implement and share your JS code so far. Thanks.

Comment: Thnks @ggorlen for responding. But I got the solution. By giving name attribute in select element i get the value in req.body. And then I can use that selected values in backend.